# how could I simulate the back key with tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I am developing a tizen native application in samsung gear s2,and I want to simulate press the back key event to get to prevous page,how could I get this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK** is  Hardware Back key event

Register the Back key event callback

eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->win, EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK, win_back_cb, ad);

Ref: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/hardware-input-handling/managing-menu-and-back-key-events